# compare 2 strings and return the number of letters that aren't equal

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, while-loop, return

I'm trying to compare 2 strings for equality and return the number of any different letters in different places if there are any e.g. *bob* and *buy* would return 2.

I've not found any other examples of this elsewhere so am trying to write the code myself. My code below isn't returning anything not sure what is wrong with it? Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

```
    function equal(str1, str2) {

    /*If the lengths are not equal, there is no point comparing each character.*/
    if (str1.length != str2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    /*loop here to go through each position and check if both strings are equal.*/

    var numDiffChar = 0;
    var index = 0;
    while (index < str1.length) {
        if (str1.charAt(index) !== str2.charAt(index)) {
            numDiffChar += index;
            index++;
        } else {

            index++;
        }
    }

 };

 equal("javascript", "JavaScript");
```

Comment: You can shorten the complete loop body to `numDiffChar += str1.charAt(index) !== str2.charAt(index); index ++;`, if you are ok with type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

```
numDiffChar += index;
```

Won't increase numDiffChar with 1 each time but with the value of `index`. I'm guessing you want to do

```
numDiffChar++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simon's answer, you're not returning the value of `numDiffChar`. Also, you always want to increment `index` anyway, so I would place that outside the `if` statement. You can bail early if the strings are equal. Suggestion:

```
function equal(str1, str2) {

    /* If the strings are equal, bail */
    if (str1 === str2) {
        return 0;
    }

    /*If the lengths are not equal, there is no point comparing each character.*/
    if (str1.length != str2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    /*loop here to go through each position and check if both strings are equal.*/
    var numDiffChar = 0;
    var index = 0;
    while (index < str1.length) {
        if (str1.charAt(index) !== str2.charAt(index)) {
            numDiffChar++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return numDiffChar;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

function equal(str1, str2) {

```
/*If the lengths are not equal, there is no point comparing each character.*/
if (str1.length != str2.length) {
    return false;
}

/*loop here to go through each position and check if both strings are equal.*/
else
{
var numDiffChar = 0;
var index = 0;
while (index < str1.length) {
    if (str1.charAt(index) !== str2.charAt(index)) {
        numDiffChar += index;
        index++;
    } else {

        index++;
    }
}
}
```

};

equal("javascript", "JavaScript");

Comment: Or put ELSE before "var numDiffChar=0"